# CUDA stream ID inside kernel

Tags: cuda

How to find out the current execution stream ID inside a kernel function? I'd expect a predefined variable similar to blockIdx, or threadIdx, but can't find any mentioning of a "streamId". Is there another way?

Answer (score 7):

In CUDA, streams are a host driver facility - effectively just a series of command pipelines from which the driver selects tasks to initiate on the GPU. In the "basic" CUDA architecture, the GPU has a "DMA engine" for memory transfers on the PCI express bus, and an "execution engine" for executing kernel code and that's it. On Fermi there can be up to two "DMA engines" and the "execution engine" seems to be host driver confiugrable to allow multiple kernel execution. The driver pushes work from one or more FIFO buffers (which are exposed via the streams API) onto those engines. But the GPU itself doesn't know anything about streams, they are soley a host side apparatus.

Answer (score 7):

If you need the stream ID in the kernel, you could always pass it in as a parameter to your kernel:

```
__global___
void kernel(int streamId) {
    //...
}

void callKernel() {
    cudaStream_t stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    kernel<<<1,1,0,stream>>>((int)stream);
}
```

Comment: In both the CUDA runtime and the driver API, the stream ID is a void *:

typedef struct CUstream_st *cudaStream_t;

typedef struct CUstream_st *CUstream;

Comment: Interesting, [this documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__TYPES_g4d9eac679936eb86c04477230353efd1.html#g4d9eac679936eb86c04477230353efd1) showed it as `typedef int cudaStream_t` It looks like they changed it in more recent versions, or the docs are incorrect

Comment: In version 5.0 of the CUDA toolkit and on 64bit, sizeof(cudaStream_t)==8